# jquery siblings() getting pervious sibling instead of next

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-traversing

hey guys hope you can help me out.

I am relatively new to jquery and having some trouble traversing a table.

basically I have this

```
<tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG" rel="#mies1" border="0" alt="SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG">
                        <br />SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG <input type="checkbox" name="SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG"  value="SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG" border="0" alt="SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG">
                        <br />SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG <input type="checkbox" name="SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG" value="SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG" border="0" alt="SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG">
                        <br />SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG <input type="checkbox" name="SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG" value="SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0966c.JPG" border="0" alt="SatchelTobyCole_0966c.JPG">
                        <br />SatchelTobyCole_0966c.JPG <input type="checkbox" name="SatchelTobyCole_0966c.JPG" value="SatchelTobyCole_0966c.JPG">
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

now I am pasting a part of code of a bigger function. Basically the part of code I am pasting is a little modification of the actual to explain the problem

```
src="SatchelTobyCole_0963c.JPG";
var checkbox=$("#getPix input:checkbox[name='"+src+"']");
alert(checkbox.parent("td").siblings("td").children("img").attr("src"));
```

Now I want the alert to say "120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0966.JPG"

BUT, instead, it is saying

"120628SatchelTobyCole/thumbnails/SatchelTobyCole_0963.JPG".

i.e, I want the alert to print the source of the next image in the table yet it is printing it of the previous?

if any one could explain what I am doing wrong and how to correct it I would be very greatful. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.siblings` gets all siblings and `.attr` gets the value of the first selected element. Try using `.next()` instead of `.siblings()` so that you get the next td's image rather than the first td's image.

```
alert(checkbox.parent("td").next().children("img").attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use next(). You can currently using parent.sibligs so it will find  and its elements
See JSFiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/bMWZm/